# How to retrieve data from set with drush_set_option() from within install profile

Tags: distributions, drush

I've been messing around with trying to pass varabiles to an install profile based on a signup form, as descripbed in [this post](http://groups.drupal.org/node/97039). I'm able to get the data out of the form and into drush using `hook_pre_provision_install()`, but I'm not sure how to grab that data from within the install profile that was set with [drush_set_option()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!includes!context.inc/function/drush_set_option/7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer is simple: You can use [drush_get_option()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!includes!context.inc/function/drush_get_option/7).

> Get the value for an option.
>
> If the first argument is an array, then it checks whether one of the options exists and return the value of the first one found. Useful for allowing both `-h`, and `--host-name`.